# Почему мой скрипт ничего не возвращает?

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

Я пишу программу, которая должна выводить какой-то ответ в зависимости от того, что выбрано в нескольких select тегах
main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Converter</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <select name="type" id="type">
      <option></option>
      <option value="pp">Промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="ppp">Потенциально промышленные проекты</option>
      <option value="np">Некоммерческие проекты </option>
    </select>
    <div id="project"></div>
    <div id="response"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const type = document.getElementById("type");
      const project = document.getElementById("project");
      const response = document.getElementById("response");
      var scnd;

      async function changeOption_(){
        let request = scnd.value;
        let result = await eel.listener(request)();
        response.innerHTML = result;
      }

      function changeOption(){
        if (type.value == "pp"){
          project.innerHTML = `<select name="scnd" id="scnd">
            <option value=\"vr\">В разработке</option>
            <option value=\"ukr\">Утверждённые к разработке</option>
            <option value=\"okr\">Обоснованные к разработке</option>
          </select>`;
          scnd = document.getElementById("scnd");
          scnd.addEventListener("change", changeOption_);
        } else if(type.value == "ppp"){
          project.innerHTML = `<select name="scnd" id="scnd">
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"ro\">Разработка ожидается/задерживается</option>
          </select>`;
          scnd = document.getElementById("scnd");
          scnd.addEventListener("change", changeOption_);
        }else{
          project.innerHTML = `<select name="scnd" id="scnd">
            <option value=\"n\">None</option>
            <option value=\"rnv\">Разработка не выяснена/нецелесообразна</option>
          </select>`;
          scnd = document.getElementById("scnd");
          scnd.addEventListener("change", changeOption_);
        }
      }


      type.addEventListener("change", changeOption);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.py

```
import eel

eel.init("web")

eel.start("main.html", size=(700,700))

criteries = {'vr':'Probable Reserves'}

@eel.expose
def listener(code): 
    return criteries.get(code)
```

Но когда я ввожу данные в надежде получить Probable Reserves, я не получаю ничего, никаких ошибок в отлатчике

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во первых

```
eel.start("main.html", size=(700,700))
```

надо в самом конце, во вторых что бы всё вывелось надо в самой функции вместо `return criteries.get(code)` написать `print(criteries.get(code))`

то-есть код будет

```
import eel

criteries = {'vr':'Probable Reserves'}

@eel.expose
def listener(code): 
    print(criteries.get(code))

eel.init("web")
eel.start("main.html", size=(700,700))
```

если хочешь что бы данные куда то отправлялись то

```
import eel

criteries = {'vr':'Probable Reserves'}

def func(obj):
    pass
    # ваш код

@eel.expose
def listener(code): 
    func(obj="что-то")

eel.init("web")
eel.start("main.html", size=(700,700))
```